# Loading external image on SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a picture box on SSRS.  I want to load a picture to it, for exam from 
D:\Pictures\TV1.jpg  (actually user will decide it by using OpenFileDialog)

I have set the Source to external and in Value expression I tired
="D:\Pictures\TV1.jpg"
and 
Also tried

```
="/<D:\Pictures>\TV1.jpg"
```

but my picture box shows error picture in both cases.

Please advise what is wrong.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put file:D:\TV1.jpg in the value property.

=" not to be used..........

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
="file:D:\Pictures\TV1.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works; you only have to ensure the server running SSRS can access the drive letter indicate i.e. upload the photo to a drive visible to the server.

="file:D:\Pictures\TV1.jpg"